# Simultaneous find and replace

Tags: replace, find

Is there a way to perform a simultaneous find and replace?

e.g.: I want to replace all `1` for `0` and simultaneously all `0` to `1`

```
[
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
]
```

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can do that by using an expression. For this particular case, you can use Vim arithmetic and calculate `1-x`, which will turn 0 into 1 and 1 into 0.

```
:s/\d/\=1-submatch(0)/g
```

For a more general replacement case, you can use a Dict to store the mapping of match to replacement string.

For example, to turn the digits into written numbers:

```
:let repl = {"0": "zero", "1": "one"}
:s/\d/\=repl[submatch(0)]/g
```

See:

- [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)
- [`:help /\d`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cd)
- [`:help submatch()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29)
- [`:help Dict`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#Dict)

Comment: I love the elegance of the first solution. And the dict mapping in your second solution is a handy technique to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

There's a bunch of excellent answers here already, but for the sake of completeness I feel like I should point out that, in most *practical* respects, if you concatenate multiple ex commands with the [bar character `|`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar), they act like a single operation.

In particular, they will lead to a single item in each of the [undo tree](https://vimhelp.org/usr_32.txt.html) and [changelist](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#changelist).

As such, the following acts like a simultaneous change of 1 to 0 and 0 to 1:

```
:%s/1/TEMP/g | %s/0/1/g | %s/TEMP/0/g
```

Comment: I like these kind of solutions; the other ones are more clever and arguably better, but this one is easier to remember and has lower cognitive load. Sometimes I spend more time getting the "clever" method to work than I save by just using the "dumb" method. Maybe I'm just not smart enough heh

Answer (score 8):

In your specific use case, i think what you can do is this handy oneline:

```
%s/0\|1/\=!submatch(0)/g
```

That basically inverts the match.

Answer (score 7):

Sure:

```
%s/[01]/\="10"[submatch(0)]/g
```

Matches either a `0` or `1` and replaces it with either

`"10"[0]` = `1`

or

`"10"[1]` = `0`

Answer (score 7):

This answer is longer than others, it didn't take the specific data value advantage, it's a general solution to replace n different values with n different replacements:

```
let d={0:1,1:0} | %s/\v(0|1)/\=d[submatch(0)]/g | unlet d
```

So if you want to change `Hello vim 8` to `Oh god 9` in a single replacement:

```
let d={'Hello':'Oh','vim':'god',8:9} | %s/\v(Hello|vim|8)/\=d[submatch(0)]/g | unlet d
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm actually surprised there is no native [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) in vi/vim, but if your platform is UNIXy enough, there's an external command for just this:

```
:%!tr 01 10
```

This is what I would personally use, but it may not be portable enough for you.

Comment: there is `:h tr()`

Comment: And from the function, we can define a command: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25665554/15934

Answer (score 5):

I'm quite certain I've already gave an answer to the general case either here on vi.SE, or on stackoverflow, but impossible to find the Q/A...

In that answer I provide the command `CycleSubstitute` that could be used in your case in the following way

```
:[range]CycleSubstitute/0/1
```

I've packaged it [here](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/rotate_substitute.vim#L36). And it's implemented in the following way:

```
:command! -bang -nargs=1 -range CycleSubstitute <line1>,<line2>call s:CycleSubstitute("<bang>", <f-args>)

function! s:CycleSubstitute(bang, repl_arg) range
  let do_loop = a:bang != "!"
  let sep = a:repl_arg[0]
  let fields = split(a:repl_arg, sep)
  let cleansed_fields = map(copy(fields), 'substitute(v:val, "\\\\[<>]", "", "g")')
  " build the action to execute
  let action = '\=s:DoCycleSubst('.do_loop.',' . string(cleansed_fields) . ', "^".submatch(0)."$")'
  " prepare the :substitute command
  let args = [join(fields, '\|'), action ]
  let cmd = a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 's'
        \. sep . join(fields, '\|')
        \. sep . action
        \. sep . 'g'
  " echom cmd
  " and run it
  exe cmd
endfunction

function! s:DoCycleSubst(do_loop, fields, what)
  let idx = (match(a:fields, a:what) + 1) % len(a:fields)
  return a:fields[idx]
endfunction
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @LucHermitte's answer, the [SwapStrings plugin](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#SWAPSTRINGS) lets you do

```
:%SwapStrings 0 1
```

My own [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides (among many others) a `:SubstituteMultiple` command that can do swaps as a corner case of doing multiple substitutions atomically (that is, without introducing a temp replacement):

```
:%SubstituteMultiple /0/1/ /1/0/ g
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the list of plugins allowing this, [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) features the `Subvert` function which can be leveraged to achieve multiple replaces:

```
%Subvert/{1,0}/{0,1}/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\([01]\)/\=1-submatch(1)/g
```

The following is taking place in the substitute command

- Search for 1 or 0, remember it as submatch 1 (between the first / and second /)
- Replace with the value by subtracting from 1 (between the second / and third /)
- 1 becomes 0 and 0 becomes 1

\= is interpreted as the beginning of a mathematical expression in the substituted section

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Good answers usually provide an explanation alongside code in order to be instructive