# vim. How do you replace 'x' with 'y' and 'y' with 'x'?

Tags: vimscript, gvim

I don't want to do this manually, and I'm sure there is a way for vim to do it. I probably am not googling the correct question to find the result I want, but here is what I want to do.
I have this block of code:

```
    // Move the topSideLeft point to the topLeft corner
    topSideLeft->left = new MapChunk;
    topSideLeft->left->right = topSideLeft;
    topSideLeft->left->bottom = topSideLeft->bottom->left;
    topSideLeft->bottom->left->top = topSideLeft->left;
    // Move the topSideRight point to the topRight corner
    topSideRight->right = new MapChunk;
    topSideRight->right->left = topSideRight;
    topSideRight->right->bottom = topSideRight->bottom->right;
    topSideRight->bottom->right = topSideRight->right;
```

What I want to do is have all the text that says bottom be top, and all the text that says top be bottom.

Example:

```
    // Move the bottomSideLeft point to the bottomLeft corner
    bottomSideLeft->left = new MapChunk;
    bottomSideLeft->left->right = bottomSideLeft;
    bottomSideLeft->left->top = bottomSideLeft->top->left;
    bottomSideLeft->top->left->bottom = topSideLeft->left;
    // Move the bottomSideRight point to the bottomRight corner
    bottomSideRight->right = new MapChunk;
    bottomSideRight->right->left = topSideRight;
    bottomSideRight->right->top = bottomSideRight->top->right;
    bottomSideRight->top->right = bottomSideRight->right;
```

It would be something like: s/top/bottom/g & s/bottom/top/g, but like at the same time so it replaces it with each other rather than just replacing either top or bottom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I replace two distinct old strings with two distinct new strings using a single :s command?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34832/can-i-replace-two-distinct-old-strings-with-two-distinct-new-strings-using-a-sin)  Note the mention of the plugin abolish...if you don't mind using a plugin that will do the trick for you. (I just tried it with your example as a matter of fact and it works nicely.)

Comment: Dang. Lol. It basically says it isn't possible unless you install a plugin or get VERY fancy with regex. Hmmm. But it does answer it.

Comment: Yes, that's true. :) Welcome to Vi&Vim SE, BTW.

Comment: This one is perhaps also relevant: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24977/18609

Comment: @filbranden That one's mentioned in a comment under the dupe question and I mention that comment in my answer to the dupe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Can I replace two distinct old strings with two distinct new strings using a single :s command?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34832/can-i-replace-two-distinct-old-strings-with-two-distinct-new-strings-using-a-sin)

Sometimes people ask questions in such different ways that it makes it near impossible for the search engine to figure out the correct stack overflow link to send you to.