# How to swap every two words in the whole text?

Tags: replace

I have such codes:

```
int flag1 = GetWidget(widget);
flag1.append(widget);
delete widget;
```

I'm willing to swap every `flag1` and `widget` in the whole text, i.e.:

```
int widget = GetWidget(flag1);
widget.append(flag1);
delete flag1;
```

I've tried replace every `flag1` with an unused word (like `dfgsergwer`) and then replace `widget` to `flag1` and finally replace `dfgsergwer` to `widget`, but it seems not intuitive.

Any way to do it elegantly?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! How does https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24980/10604 compare to what you want?